# How to access ActiveJob Logger at rescue_from block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, resque, rails-activejob

If I log inside the `perform()` I get a pretty output:

```
  def perform(*args)
    begin
      MyActivity.run(*args)
    rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.debug e
      raise e
    end
  end
```

`13:55:10 resque.1 | [ActiveJob] [MyJob] [18cd0f78-d784-48a7-a573-0b3aa95c51cc] Connection refused - connect(2) for "fe80::1%lo0" port 3000`

If I log inside `rescue_from` block I don't get the Tags/Labels of `ActiveJob` or `JobId`

```
rescue_from(StandardError) do |e|
  Rails.logger.debug e
end
```

`13:55:11 resque.1 | Connection refused - connect(2) for "fe80::1%lo0" port 3000`

I presume that on the `rescue_from` block the Job is already terminated, so we don't have the `JobId` anymore.

Is there a way to get the output just like the log inside `perform`?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I could do like this:

```
  rescue_from(StandardError) do |e|
    Rails.logger.debug "[ActiveJob] [#{self.class}] [#{job_id}] #{e}"
  end
```

What's even better is that I can write this code inside `application_job.rb` if I wan't to log any kind of error for any job.